# Etale fundamental group of the circle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

What is the étale fundamental group of the circle $X({\bf R})$, where
$$
X(k) = \{(x,y) \in k^2 \mid x^2+y^2 = 1\}?
$$
I know that there is a sequence
$$
1 \rightarrow \pi_1^{et}(X({\bf C})) \rightarrow \pi_1^{et}(X({\bf R})) \rightarrow Gal({\bf C}/{\bf R}) \rightarrow 1
$$
with $Gal({\bf C}/{\bf R})= \{z\mapsto z, z\mapsto \bar{z}\}$. The first group is the profinite completion of $\bf Z$ since $X({\bf C})$ is the projective complex line with two points removed, but I don't know if the sequence splits or not.
More generally, what can be said about that sequence for general smooth varieties over ${\bf R}$?

Comment: The sequence should split if $X(\mathbb{R})$ has a real point, since the point would induce a section. So in particular, this should split for the circle.

Comment: Note that the middle term is $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X_{\mathbf R})$, not $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X(\mathbf R))$. The latter doesn't make sense as $X(\mathbf R)$ is only a set; the scheme $X_{\mathbf R}$ needs a lot more information than its set of $\mathbf R$-points. This issue is especially poignant if $X(\mathbf R) = \varnothing$, which by Donu's comment is exactly the case where something more interesting may happen. (Actually the split case is also interesting, as you still need to determine which semi-direct product you get, i.e. what the Galois action on the geometric fundamental group is.)

Comment: So the étale fundamental group of the circle is the direct product of $\hat{\bf Z}$ by ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$? How disappointing.

Comment: It might be a semi-direct product in this case. It seems that complex conjugation acts via multiplication by -1 on the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$, no?

Comment: For this variety the real points are a circle, a deformation retract of the complex points. The real points carry the whole fundamental group, but conjugation acts trivially on real points and thus trivially on the fundamental group of the real points, but that is the whole fundamental group of the complex points, so the action is trivial. Whereas, for the multiplicative group, the real points are two lines, the positive real numbers and the negative real numbers, both with trivial fundamental group, so this does not bound the action on $\pi_1 C^*$. In that case, the action is by $-1$.

Comment: @BenWieland I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, but would love to see your comment turned into an answer. Or at least do you have some references?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Ben's claim is that we can use that complex conjugation is continuous, and that the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ on $\pi_1^{et}(X_\mathbf C)$ can be identified with the purely topologically defined action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ on $\pi_1^{top}(X(\mathbf C))$, profinitely completed. But the latter action is trivial since $\pi_1^{top}(X(\mathbf R)) \to \pi_1^{top}(X(\mathbf C))$ is an isomorphism and the Galois group acts trivially on $X(\mathbf R)$.

Comment: Similarly for $X=\mathbb G_m$ one can instead write down a loop defining a generator of $\pi_1^{top}(\mathbb G_m(\mathbf C))$ whose complex conjugate is its inverse.

Comment: @DanPetersen thanks; that's indeed much more insightful than my "unwinding the definitions" answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Donu explained, the sequence splits by choosing an $\mathbf R$-point of $X$. So the only question remaining is what the $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$-action on $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X_{\mathbf C})$ is. I claim that the action is trivial, because the two points at infinity $V(x^2+y^2)$ are not defined over $\mathbf R$. (By contrast, for $\mathbf G_{m,\mathbf R}$ we get the nontrivial action where a generator $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ acts by $-1$, using the same argument as below.)

Indeed, consider the tower $Y_n \to X_{\mathbf C} \to X$ where $Y_n \to X_{\mathbf C}$ is the unique cover of degree $n$. The composite $Y_n \to X$ is Galois as $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X_{\mathbf C}) \trianglelefteq \pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X)$ is normal and $n\mathbf Z \subseteq \mathbf Z$ is characteristic (in other words, any conjugate $Y'_n$ would contain $X_{\mathbf C}$ as $X_{\mathbf C} \to X$ is normal, hence $Y'_n \cong Y_n$ as $X_{\mathbf C}$-covers since $Y_n$ is the unique degree $n$ cover).

We need to compute $\operatorname{Gal}(Y_n/X)$. This depends on some choices of isomorphisms: we choose $X_{\mathbf C} \stackrel\sim\to \mathbf G_{m,\mathbf C}$ via $(x,y) \mapsto x+yi$, and we write $t = x+yi$. Under this identification, the generator $\sigma$ of $\operatorname{Gal}(X_{\mathbf C}/X) = \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ acts on $\mathbf G_{m,\mathbf C}$ via $x+yi \mapsto x-yi$, i.e. the $\mathbf C$-semilinear map $\sum_j c_jt^j \mapsto \sum_j \bar c_jt^{-j}$.

Then $Y_n$ can be identified with $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf C[t^{\pm1/n}]$. The Galois group of $Y_n$ over $Y_1$ is $\mu_n(\mathbf C)$, where $\zeta \in \mu_n(\mathbf C)$ acts as the $\mathbf C$-linear map $t \mapsto \zeta t$. The conjugation action of $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(X_{\mathbf C}/X)$ on $\operatorname{Gal}(Y_n/X_{\mathbf C})$ is therefore trivial, as
$$(\sigma \circ \zeta \circ \sigma^{-1})(t) = (\sigma \circ \zeta)(t^{-1}) = \sigma (\zeta^{-1}t^{-1}) = \overline{\zeta^{-1}}t = \zeta t.$$
Thus, we see that the conjugation action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf C/\mathbf R)$ on $\pi_1^{\text{ét}}(X_{\mathbf C})$ is trivial. $\square$

Comment: Since you're working with the étale fundamental group, you're looking at actions on $\hat{\mathbb Z}$, which are not unique. I guess you can use the fact that complex conjugation is continuous to get an action on the usual fundamental group, but probably easier to say the action where the generator acts by inversion...

Comment: @WillSawin fixed, and also fixed a mistake in my argument (leading to the opposite conclusion of what I claimed!).

Comment: Nice answer @R. van Dobben de Bruyn. It's tricky to work out the complex conjugation without sign mistakes. Maybe way to think about it is in terms of the group structure, because in this case we have a form of $\mathbb{G}_m$ (I guess this is what your identification is doing). The covering of the base change to the complex numbers is just multiplication by n, which is actually defined over the reals for our original variety.

Comment: As you note, the group of deck transformations is the group of complex points of the kernel defined over the reals, which has a natural Galois action (I think this coincides with conjugation if we follow the definition of things). The kernel of multiplication by n in this case is the constant cyclic group over the reals, whereas for $\mathbb{G}_m$ you get $\mu_n$ (you can see both of these things quickly by looking at the groups of character as Galois modules). This is a equivalent way to see the Galois action. Somehow it seems a bit easier to think about.

Comment: @coudy it's because $x+yi$ is sent to $x-yi$, which is $\frac{1}{x+yi}$ as $x^2+y^2=1$.